# YAML error when knitting with one new line of code adding single bibliography line

Tags: yaml, r-markdown

following yaml line of code (Code is at line 10 and line 9 and 11 through 13 are blank where the yaml ends)

```yaml
bibliography:dcf_bibliography.bib
```

when knitting to  PDF format which knits fine without the line of code

results in this error

```
messageError in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning a simple key at line 9, column 3 could not find expected ':' at line 12, column 5
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space missing after the colon. Fix it like this:

```yaml
bibliography: dcf_bibliography.bib
```

It is not certain this is the only error as you don't show the whole YAML file.

Comment: Thanks. That allows code to run again.  However, my attempt to have all my references listed using the code provided elsewhere on stack overflow (below) results in none listed.  The .bib file is in the proper directory.                                            # References

---
nocite: '@*'
...

Comment: @123blee Well if you have another issue please open a new question, comments are not the right tool for that.